# como capturar el evento click del span

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo la siguiente funcion javascript:

```
function LoadDataTable(data) {     

          $('#table-labresult').bootstrapTable("load", data);
          $table.bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {
                pageSize: 5,                    
                columns: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, 
                {
                    field: 'download',
                    title: 'Export',
                    align: 'center',
                    valign: 'middle',
                    clickToSelect: true,
                    width: '5%',
                    formatter: function (value, row, index) {
                        return '<span RecNo="' + row.RecNo + '" IsFileCompress="' + row.IsFileCompress + '" class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt downl"></span>';

                    }
                }
                ]
            });         
        }
```

Lo que me haria falta es cuando se de clic en el span me de aunque sea un console.log(Recno);

Como puedo obtener ese atributo al dar click en el span

probe con esto:

```
onclick="clickdownload($this.RecNo)"
```

Esto me da un error y me dice que clickdownload is not defined, y si esta definida

Comment: Probaste usando `onclick` en la etiqueta span y pasas como parámetro el atributo?

Comment: hola Federico voy a actualiar el codigo con lo que probe, algo parecido a lo que me dices

Answer (score 2):

Puedes probar con esta variante cuando utilizas datatables:

```
$('#table-labresult tbody').on( 'click', '#span', function () {
        console.log('Click on Span');

});
```

Comment: perfecto LuiscYm gracias

Answer (score 1):

Usa un atributo ID en tu **span**:

Y en el jquery:

```
<script>

        $("#span").click( function()
           {
             console.log(Recno);
           }
        );
</script>
```

Comment: Hola Joel esa variante fue la primera que use, y me lo hace perfecto, pero cuando pagino la tabla no me funciona

Comment: se escribe span